# psql connections using environment variables on mac?

Tags: postgresql, macos

I would like to connect to a postgres instance using the cli from my Mac, using [environment variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html).  However, this doesn't seem to work as advertised on Mac:

```
$ PGHOST=stackoverflow.com
$ echo $PGHOST
stackoverflow.com
$ psql
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

Why isn't psql using my environment variables to find the host, etc on MacOS?

Comment: Presumably Mac is like Linux in this aspect.  In bash on Linux, if you don't `export` the variable, then it is only set for the purposes of the shell, not for purposes of programs launched by the shell.